# Why methods in Collection interface are again declared in List Interface though List extends Collection

Tags: java, collections, interface, java-11

I checked the source code of java `Collection` interface and `List` interface. Some of the methods in `Collection` interface e.g `int size()`, are re-declared in `List` interface though it is not necessary as `List extends the Collection` interface.(Java 11).

Comment: Well, there can be a number of reasons but I'd bet a major reason is that this way more specific Javadocs can be added.

Comment: @Thomas Javadoc for `size` is same.

Comment: @talex you're right (albeit there _is_ one difference ;) but still you _could_ add a more specific Javadoc. Besides that, there's no real technical need and some decisions are up to the devs - and I doubt they documented _all_ their decisions and the reasoning behind them. Some things should just be taken as a given, if they don't harm us, why bother?

Answer (score 3):

A method in a sub-interface may have different behavior (or at least a more specific behavior) than a method of the super interface having the exact same signature.

Therefore, it is very useful, for example, for the users of the `List` interface to know that `add`

> Appends the specified element to the end of this list

which is more specific than the general description of `add` in the `Collection` interface:

> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional operation)

Since Java 8 there's another reason for methods to be re-declared in sub-interfaces, and that reason is `default` interface implementations. You can see that `Spliterator<E> spliterator()` is defined in `List`, `Collection` & `Iterable`, and in each interface it has a different default implementation.

I agree that your example of re-defining `size()` in `List` makes less sense, since the Javadoc is practically identical to that of `size()` in `Collection`.

Comment: it seems that the *only* change in the doc is `collection` -> `list` change, looks kind of too thin, don't you think?

Comment: I honestly think this was a "bulk" copy of all methods and redefinition of java-docs indeed, even if this change for `size` is rather small

Comment: @Eugene what do you mean? The `List` interface mentions the order (end of the `List`), while `Collection` doesn't make any assumptions about order.

Comment: I mean the OP is asking about `size`, in that method the only java-doc change is a single word

Comment: @Eugene OP gave `size` as a example, but the title seems to ask about re-declared methods in general. I agree that for `size` the re-declaration seems redundant.

Comment: @Eugene sometimes, methods were redeclared in subtypes for subtle performance implications, only the JRE/JVM maintainer know about.